# Excel Font Color Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula in a cell that concatenates text and a calculation to output an amount of money someone owes, like the following:

[image]

What I would like to do now is highlight only the dollar amount in that formula to be red, so the result would look like this:

[image]

*The above was made by pasting the formula as a value and manually editing the font color*

Looking online it doesn't look like this is something I could accomplish outside of using VBA.  Potentially Custom Formatting would do it, but I don't know how I would limit that to only certain text in the cell.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Regex can be helpful here as you have pattern and can be highlighted by using VBA code.

Comment: @pnuts, I think that's a fair point. I just did a quick search to see what's out there and the first things that came up are 1. how to achieve manually 2. how to using VBA ... but I didn't quickly find a link that made it clear it's not possible to do so using a formula (perhaps just [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/527746/coloring-partial-text-within-cell-in-excel#comment638036_527746)). In fact, even the answer given to this question is evidence of this trend.

Comment: Yes I did some research before posting this question (as I mentioned in the post, and always do before posting any questions), and as CallumDA saw everything points to either using VBA, which isn't an option, or conditional formatting which doesn't format specific text.  Might just be that this isn't doable outside of VBA, which is an acceptable answer.  I just wanted to see if anyone out there knew another way to go about this

Answer (score -1):

Try this snippet

```
Sub ColorCells()

     Const RED = -16776961

    Dim rngCell As Range, rngRange As Range
    Dim Pos As Variant

    'sample area
    Set rngRange = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10")

    For Each rngCell In rngRange

        'only for text values
        If Application.IsText(rngCell) Then

            'find first occurence of dollar sign
            Pos = InStr(1, rngCell.Text, "$")

            If Application.IsNumber(Pos) And Pos <> 0 Then

                'color it starting from "$" to the end of the string
                rngCell.Characters(Pos, Len(rngCell.Text) - Pos + 1).Font.Color = RED

            End If
        End If

   Next rngCell

End Sub
```

Comment: I downvoted this answer because OP specifically notes that they are looking for a solution outside of VBA - and furthermore, the question hasn't been tagged with either VBA or Excel-VBA